# Loop to create multiple lists, with different naming

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, conditional-statements

I would like to create a loop that creates multiple lists, named differently.
I have a dataframe that contains an excel file that I am trying to filter through depending on the month. (ideally the list should be 1, 2 , 3, etc.)
Each month should create a list
In the end I need to loop through those lists again to count the average and count len
If you have any questions let me know.

```
import pandas as pd

#read data
excel = 'short data.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(excel, parse_dates=['Closed Date Time'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# data.info()
#Format / delete time from date column
data['Closed Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Closed Date Time'])
df['Close_Date'] = data['Closed Date Time'].dt.date
df['Close_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Close_Date'])

#loop to create multiple lists
times = 12

for _ in range(times):
    if times <= 9:
        month = df[df['Close_Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m') == f'2018-0{times}']
    month = df[df['Close_Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m') == f'2018-{times}']
```

example data
[[image: example data1]

Comment: hi, would be nice if you post part of your data :)

Comment: don't create lists with ddifferently names but single dictionary with names as keys or even better create single dataframe with different columns or rows

Comment: you can use `f{times:02}` to convert values `1...9`  into strings `"00"..."09"` without `if times <= 9:`

Comment: simpler `(df['Close_Date'].dt.month == times) & (df['Close_Date'].dt.year == 2018)`

Comment: maybe you should create column with `df['year-month'] = df['Close_Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')`, and use `groupby('year-month')` to make calculations on every month without using `for`-loops - ie. average: `df.groupby('year-month').mean()`, len: `df.groupby('year-month').size()`

Comment: I like the idea of a dictionary with different keys and then the lists so i can search through it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating lists with different names can be totally wrong idea.

You should rather create single list with sublisst (and indexes instead of names) or single dictinary with names as keys. Or even better you should create single `DataFrame` with all values (in rows or columns). It will be more useful for next calculations.

And all this may not need `for`-loop.

---

But I think you may do it in different way. You could create column with `Year Month`

```
df['Year_Month'] = df['Close_Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

And later use `groupby()` to execute function on every month without using `for`-loops.

```
averages = df.groupby('Year_Month').mean()

sizes = df.groupby('Year_Month').size()
```

---

Minimal working code with example data:

```
import pandas as pd

#df = pd.read_excel('short data.xlsx', parse_dates=['Closed Date Time'])

data = {
    'Closed Date Time': ['2022.10.25 01:00', '2022.10.24 01:00', '2018.10.25 01:00', '2018.10.24 01:00', '2018.10.23 01:00'],
    'Price': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'User': ['A','A','A','B','C'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df['Closed Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Closed Date Time'])
df['Close_Date'] = df['Closed Date Time'].dt.date
df['Close_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Close_Date'])

df['Year_Month'] = df['Close_Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
print(df)

print('\n--- averages ---\n')
averages = df.groupby('Year_Month').mean()
print(averages)

print('\n--- sizes ---\n')
sizes = df.groupby('Year_Month').size()
print(sizes)
```

Result:

```
   Closed Date Time  Price
0  2022.10.25 01:00      1
1  2022.10.24 01:00      2
2  2018.10.25 01:00      3
3  2018.10.24 01:00      4
4  2018.10.23 01:00      5

     Closed Date Time  Price Close_Date Year_Month
0 2022-10-25 01:00:00      1 2022-10-25    2022-10
1 2022-10-24 01:00:00      2 2022-10-24    2022-10
2 2018-10-25 01:00:00      3 2018-10-25    2018-10
3 2018-10-24 01:00:00      4 2018-10-24    2018-10
4 2018-10-23 01:00:00      5 2018-10-23    2018-10

--- averages ---

            Price
Year_Month       
2018-10       4.0
2022-10       1.5

--- sizes ---

Year_Month
2018-10    3
2022-10    2
dtype: int64
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
data = df.groupby('Year_Month').agg({'Price':['mean','size']})
print(data)
```

Result:

```
           Price     
            mean size
Year_Month           
2018-10      4.0    3
2022-10      1.5    2
```

---

**EDIT:**

Example with `.groupby()` and `.apply()` to execute more complex function.

And later it uses `.to_dict()` and `.plot()`

```
import pandas as pd

#df = pd.read_excel('short data.xlsx', parse_dates=['Closed Date Time'])

data = {
    'Closed Date Time': ['2022.10.25 01:00', '2022.10.24 01:00', '2018.10.25 01:00', '2018.10.24 01:00', '2018.10.23 01:00'],
    'Price': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'User': ['A','A','A','B','C'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#print(df)

df['Closed Date Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Closed Date Time'])
df['Close_Date'] = df['Closed Date Time'].dt.date
df['Close_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Close_Date'])

df['Year_Month'] = df['Close_Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
#print(df)

def calculate(group):
    #print(group)
    #print(group['Price'].mean())
    #print(group['User'].unique().size)
    result = {
        'Mean':  group['Price'].mean(),
        'Users': group['User'].unique().size,
        'Div':   group['Price'].mean()/group['User'].unique().size
    }
    return pd.Series(result)
    
data = df.groupby('Year_Month').apply(calculate)

print(data)

print('--- dict ---')
print(data.to_dict())
#print(data.to_dict('dict'))

print('--- records ---')
print(data.to_dict('records'))

print('--- list ---')
print(data.to_dict('list'))

print('--- index ---')
print(data.to_dict('index'))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data.plot(kind='bar', rot=0)
plt.show()
```

Result:

```
            Mean  Users       Div
Year_Month                       
2018-10      4.0    3.0  1.333333
2022-10      1.5    1.0  1.500000
--- dict ---
{'Mean': {'2018-10': 4.0, '2022-10': 1.5}, 'Users': {'2018-10': 3.0, '2022-10': 1.0}, 'Div': {'2018-10': 1.3333333333333333, '2022-10': 1.5}}
--- records ---
[{'Mean': 4.0, 'Users': 3.0, 'Div': 1.3333333333333333}, {'Mean': 1.5, 'Users': 1.0, 'Div': 1.5}]
--- list ---
{'Mean': [4.0, 1.5], 'Users': [3.0, 1.0], 'Div': [1.3333333333333333, 1.5]}
--- index ---
{'2018-10': {'Mean': 4.0, 'Users': 3.0, 'Div': 1.3333333333333333}, '2022-10': {'Mean': 1.5, 'Users': 1.0, 'Div': 1.5}}
```

[image]

Comment: I need to group by year-month and then divide by users worked this month  to create average of that month.
Then that result needs to go to another list/dictionary 
so I can later create a graph hopefully

Comment: I tried to groupby('Year_Month') like mentioned but i get an finished with exit code 0 and no results

"<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000001FD5F828A00"

Comment: I added example which uses `.groupby()` with `.apply()` to run more complex function. It also show how to use `.to_dict()` and it plots bars.

Comment: did you use `print()` to display results? Did you run code in console/terminal to see errors? If you have some `try/except` then remove it to see full error messages. If you still have problem then create new question on new page and show all your code with full error message and with example data - but as text or `DataFrame(...)`, not image - so we could use it in answers.